# How can I separate nested forEach methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've really been on the grind lately trying to find out ways to eliminate having to do nested for-loops / forEach methods, and really optimize as much as I can, but I'm a little stuck on this one.  I have a list of data that is an array of objects that also contains an array of objects.  I know how to do it with separate functions if all i need is attributes from the second nested array, but my problem is that I need attributes from both, and I'm not sure how I can accomplish this without using nested loops.

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
let data = [{Id: '1234', Server: 'prime', Status: 'open', Connections: [{Type: 'xxr', ConID: '1222'}]},
 {Id: '1214', Server: 'prime', Status: 'open', Connections: [{Type: 'xxh', ConID: '1111'}, {Type: 'xxh', ConID: '1112'}]},
 {Id: '1233', Server: 'tif', Status: 'closed', Connections: [{Type: 'xml', ConID: '1212'}, {Type: 'xxr', ConID: '1233'}, {Type: 'xxh', ConID: '1111'}]}]
```

Right now this is how I'm pushing the data I need to a new array:

```
let newArray = [];

  data.forEach(server => { 
            let temp = server.Connections;
            temp.forEach(obj => {

                let newObj = {
                    ServerID: server.ID,
                    Server: server.Server,
                    Status: server.Status,
                    ConnectionID: obj.ConID
                }
                newArray.push(newObj);
            })
        })
```

I would really like to use a map in this situation if possible, instead of pushing to `newArray` through a forEach, but I'm really not sure how I can accomplish this when I need attributes from both arrays without having a nested loop.  If anyone has any suggestions about how I can do this, that would be awesome.  Maybe it isn't possible, and it just has to be a nested loop for this situation, but I feel like there is a way to separate it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: No you can't avoid nested loop in this case

Comment: @CodeManiac well that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Array's `flatMap` function.

```
let newArray = data.flatMap(server => server.Connections.map(conn => ({
    ServerID: server.Id,
    Server: server.Server,
    Status: server.Status,
    ConnectionID: conn.ConID
})));
```

Comment: Please make sure your answer can stand on its own: provide sufficient context and do not refer to other answers. (So avoid ‘Or we can even…’.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid a nested loop, but you can use `.map()`.by nesting `.map()` operations and then calling `.flat()` on the resulting array of arrays.

```
let newArray = data.map(server => {
    return server.Connections.map(obj => {
        return {
            ServerID: server.ID,
            Server: server.Server,
            Status: server.Status,
            ConnectionID: obj.ConID
        }
    });
}).flat();
```

Or, you could use `.flatMap()` for the top level `.map()` to combine the `.map()` and the `.flat()`. `.flatMap()` can be slightly more efficient.

```
let newArray = data.flatMap(server => {
    return server.Connections.map(obj => {
        return {
            ServerID: server.ID,
            Server: server.Server,
            Status: server.Status,
            ConnectionID: obj.ConID
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is there no way that these loops could be separated from each other?

Comment: @Michael - No.  Your data structure is an array of objects where each object then contains another array and you want to visit every item in the nested array.  That requires a nested loop.  I don't see what the big trouble with a nested loop is.  At least with `.map()`, it looks cleaner.

Comment: dang I was really hoping that there would be a way to separate them from each other.  Thank you for the answer though, I will read up on ```flatMap``` and the ```flat``` function.